# Why is a console log going off when it's not supposed to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically, I have a system set up where one file has a damage value, and another file has the health.

```
void Attack()
    {
        // Detect enemies in range of attack
        Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPoint.position, attackRange, enemyLayers);

        // Damage them
        foreach(Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
        {
            Debug.Log("We hit " + enemy.name);
            enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(attackDamage);
        }
    }
```

it is worth noting that attackDamage is set to 40.

for my enemy script, this is the important code

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int maxHealth = 100;
    int currentHealth;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;

        // Play hurt animation

        if (currentHealth <= 0);
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    void Die()
    {
        Debug.Log("Enemy died!");

        // Die animation

        // Disable the enemy
    }
```

The problem here is that when I run the console and the enemy it says the enemy has 60 health, it still runs the 'Enemy died!', even though that should only happen if it's equal to or under 0. By the way i'm using unity on c#

Comment: you should print the health value directly before the if-statement inside of the method `TakeDamage`, it could be that the enemy takes a hit every frame or there are multiple hits on a single frame or the parameter damage is not what you expect it is

Comment: @Anton on the first hit, it shows 60 health, then on the second, 40, then on the third, -20, so that isn't a problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct instance of the enemy? You should use `Debug.Log("Enemy died!", this);` .. that way you can click once on the log message in the console and according GameObject will be highlighted in the hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most likely issue is `hitEnemies` contains duplicates or already dead enemies. You can check if the enemy is already dead or not to solve this. You could also use `.Distinct` to remove duplicates but it will take more time to run the attack method.

Remember, a debugger can be your best friend. Use it to see what is really going on in your game. It will let you trace and follow through your code to see what is happening and why it does things.

Comment: `hitEnemies` is everytime a new fresh returned array from the physics system .. why should it contain duplicates..? I rather guess it contains some enemies that should be dead already ;)